# Intel haxm version 7.2 not digitally signed?

Tags: android, signed, haxm

Haxm not working in the latest update (version 7.2 as of posting).

After updating android studio to version 3.1.2 (probably not relevant) and updating haxm, avds will no longer work. I have not been able to code for hours due to my avd's complaining about vt-x. After searching the internet for other possible errors, uselessly checking bios if vt-x was enable (which was because I was using Intel haxm prior to update), and resting from frustration, I decided to use an older version of haxm(7.1)... and its working again! Whats going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you on Windows 7? I suspect this issue only affects 64-bit Windows 7 systems that lack a security patch, which enables support for SHA-256 code signing algorithm:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148

See also my post here:

https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/56#issuecomment-394246865

Answer (score 1):

We could downgrade the HAXM installation, Thanks for answers:

- uninstall the latest version HAXM v7.2.0 from the normal location: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe (where **XXXXX** is the user name)
- dowload the version 7.1 from: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.1.0
- unpack and install it

Good Luck)

Comment: Good idea to share the process of removal and installation. Another way to uninstall is to do so directly through control panel using windows default install features. HAXM is under the name: "Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager". After uninstalling and downloading a digitally signed haxm from github you can reinstall by launching the "intelhaxm-android.exe" executable. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

The current newest "Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM)" version 7.2 isn't digitally signed. There are some solutions on the web about disabling secure boot or using third party software to bypass digital signatures. My current work around is to use an older version of haxm. The newest version 7.2 can be downloaded from Intel's software website: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm. Being version 7.2 it isn't digitally signed, therefore did not work for me. At the bottom of the site, it stated in the useful link section that haxm is now open sourced at git hub: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases and thankfully 7.1 of haxm is digitally signed and worked for me.

Hope this helps others.